# ¿Realizar una potencia en java de forma recursiva?

Tags: java, c, recursión

[image]

Hola, querría crear un metodo en el que realizara esa función y esto es lo que he hecho:

```
private static Long eje3RecursivoFinalb(Long a, Integer n, Long ac) {
    Long result = null;
    if(n==0) {
    result = ac;
    }else if(n>0 && n%2==1) {
        result = eje3RecursivoFinalb(a, n/2,ac*ac*a);
    }else if(n>0 && n%2==0) {
        result = eje3RecursivoFinalb(a, n/2,ac*ac);
    }
    return result;
}
```

En este caso la quería hacer con acumulador, iniciando el Long ac como 1L en la llamada al método.
Cuando el exponente Integer n es impar el resultado sale bien, pero cuando es par no. Por ejemplo con las parejas a = -2 y n = 3, o a = 7 y n =7, en ambos salen bien; pero el problema esta en estas parejas en las que las n son pares: a = 10 y n = 2, o a = 5 y n = 8.
El problema estaría en el acumulador. También lo tengo hecho en recursivo no final, lo comparto por si os sirve de ayuda:

```
public static Long eje3RecusirvoNoFinal(Long a, Integer n) {
    Long result = null;
    if(n==0) {
        result = 1l;
    }else if(n>0 && n%2==1) {
        result = eje3RecusirvoNoFinal(a, n/2)*eje3RecusirvoNoFinal(a, n/2)*a;
    }else if(n>0 && n%2==0) {
        result = eje3RecusirvoNoFinal(a, n/2)*eje3RecusirvoNoFinal(a, n/2);
    }
    return result;
}
```

NOTA: Dejo la etiqueta de C, porque en C sería de forma similar, cambiando muy pocas cosas.